# How can make a cookie using selenium?

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, webdriver, setcookie

I am trying web autotest by selenium but I have a problem.

selenium make chrome profile when connect website every time so have to be sms certified every time for login.

So to solve this problem, I have tried to save a cookie. I wrote the code below but it did not work:

```
$driver = $this->driver;
$driver->get('https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbookingapi.naver.com%2Fauth%2Fcallback&user=1&locale=ko_KR');
$driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
$driver->manage()->addCookie(['name' => 'test', 'value' => 'dfsdf', 'domain' => '/', 'path' => '/', 'expiry' => '2524640402', 'secure' => false, 'httpOnly' => false]);
    Log::alert($driver->manage()->getCookies());
    $driver->quit();
```

I get the following error message:

```
[2019-06-28 00:42:42] local.ALERT: array (
)
```

Why does it not work? No errors, no results? I do not know what's wrong. Can I get help?

Comment: IDK if this will solve your problem but when you insert a cookie on selenium you have to refresh the driver for apply the cookie

Comment: just use f5 button in selenium browser ?? or other way ??

Comment: Try navigating to the same URL $driver->get(url) or "$driver->navigate()->refresh();"

Comment: What are you expecting to happen after you add the cookie? You've already navigated to the page. My guess is that you should navigate to https://nid.naver.com, create the cookie, and THEN navigate to the full URL you posted.